# Setting up ERP-next in Mac

Tags: erpnext

I have followed the GitHub to setup. I have installed pip, MariaDB, bench, Redis.
After I run the command `bench init frappe-bench and cd frappe-bench` I don't allow me to create a new site. The following is an error that IO encountered.

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/bin/python3.7: Error while finding module specification for 'frappe.utils.bench_helper' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'frappe')

Usage: bench [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
Try "bench --help" for help.

Error: No such command "new-site".
```

I have also changed in my.conf to

```
 [mysqld]
 innodb-file-format=barracuda
 innodb-file-per-table=1
 innodb-large-prefix=1
 character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
 character-set-server = utf8mb4
 collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci

 [mysql]
 default-character-set = utf8mb4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After `bench init frappe-bench`

```
cd env 
source bin/activate
pip install -e ./apps/frappe --no-cache-dir
bench build
```

Reference: https://discuss.erpnext.com/t/mac-os-setup-failed/53422/3